# React component doesn't re-render after I changed state

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 components: PhotoList and Pagination. Inside PhotoList, I use `componentDidMount` to call the api from the server based on the `currentPage` value stored in PhotoList's state.

I also wrote `pageChanged` method to change `currentPage` value and passed this method through `props` for Pagination component

```
pageChanged = (numPage) => {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: numPage
    });
    // console.log("Day la currentPage hien tai: ",this.state.currentPage);
  }
```

```
<Pagination 
            totalPages={Math.floor(this.state.totalImages/30)+1}
            clicked={this.pageChanged}
/>
```

Inside Pagination component, I called above method like this

```
<a onClick={(event) => {this.props.clicked(event.target.text)}}>2</a>
```

So I just updated the `currentPage` value but my PhotoList component didn't re-render. And another thing is when I click it for the first time, the `currentPage` value doesn't change (still is 1 *default value*) until I click it for the second time.

Pls help me. Thanks

Comment: This is not necessary realated but here `<a onClick={(event) => {this.props.clicked(event.target.text)}}>2</a>` you have acces to page number (2) so do it like this `<a onClick={(event) => {this.props.clicked(pageNumber)}}>{pageNumber}</a>`. Don't rely on DOM elements in a react component if you don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidMount()` is only called once when the component is rendered first time. You should recall the api when the `pageChanged` is called or after you called `setState`.

Also, `setState` is asynchronous, so when you clicked first time, it doesn't log the updated value.
For example, you can do like this

```
pageChanged = (numPage) => {
   this.setState({
      currentPage: numPage
   }, () => { 
      // console.log("Day la currentPage hien tai: ",this.state.currentPage);
      /* YOUR API CALL */ 
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example of setstate from one component to another
https://jsfiddle.net/singhsourav930/1ctg2k7a/7/

```
class PhotoList extends React.Component {
  /**
   * State
   */
  state = {
    currentPage: 0,
  };

  /**
   * When component did mount
   * This function trigger only once
   * Here you can set your initial values
   */
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ currentPage: 1 });
  }

  /**
   * Page changed
   * @param {Number} numPage
   */
  pageChanged = (numPage) => {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: numPage,
    });
  };

  /**
   * Render
   */
  render() {
    const { currentPage } = this.state;
    console.log(currentPage);
    return (
      <div>
        <Pagination clicked={this.pageChanged} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Pagination extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { clicked } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <a onClick={() => clicked(2)}>2</a>
        <br />
        <a onClick={() => clicked(3)}>3</a>
        <br />
        <a onClick={() => clicked(4)}>4</a>
        <br />
        <a onClick={() => clicked(5)}>5</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<PhotoList />, document.getElementById('container'));
```